# How to use ItemDecoration for GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to know how to add item decoration to have equal space between all items, and control whether to have space in each of the outer spaces

the required effects:

only left space and equal space in between:
[image]

no edges space and equal space in between:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.DimenRes
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class ItemOffsetDecoration(
    private val mItemOffset: Int,
    private val columnsSize: Int,
    private val includeEdges: EdgesIncluded
) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    constructor(context: Context, @DimenRes itemOffsetId: Int, columnsSize: Int, includeEdges: EdgesIncluded) : this(
        context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(itemOffsetId),
        columnsSize,
        includeEdges
    )

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val lp = view.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
        val columnPosition = lp.spanIndex
        val isEven = columnPosition%2 == 0
        val isTopRow = lp.viewAdapterPosition < columnsSize
        val isBottomRow =
            if (parent.adapter == null)
                true
            else
                lp.viewAdapterPosition > parent.adapter!!.itemCount - columnsSize

        val left = if (isEven) mItemOffset/2 else mItemOffset
        val top = if (isTopRow) mItemOffset else mItemOffset/2
        val right = if (isEven) mItemOffset else mItemOffset/2
        val bottom = if (isBottomRow) mItemOffset else mItemOffset/2
        outRect.set(
            if (includeEdges.leftEdge) left else if (isEven) left else 0,
            if (includeEdges.topEdge) top else 0,
            if (includeEdges.rightEdge) right else if (isEven) 0 else right,
            if (includeEdges.bottomEdge) bottom else 0
        )
    }

    data class EdgesIncluded(
        val leftEdge: Boolean = true,
        val topEdge: Boolean = true,
        val rightEdge: Boolean = true,
        val bottomEdge: Boolean = true
    )
}
```